# Facebook share cropping image

Tags: facebook

When I share portrait orientation images using the FB SDK they turn up as cropped landscape orientation images on the FB wall - chopping off the top and bottom.

I got the OG tag in my page like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://graphics.myfavnews.com/images/logo-100x100.jpg" />
```

Is there a way to give FB instructions on how to crop (or not to)?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any way of specifying cropping or scaling requirements for the image in the og:image tag. According to the Facebook docs, images should follow a 1.91:1 aspect ratio. This should prevent the image from being cropped.

There are some additional details about optimizing images here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images